# Why does clicked item not getting selected on dropdown instead it always shows title text

Tags: html, angular, typescript, twitter-bootstrap

My dropdown always shows the title text on it `Select Location` not showing selected item even though the `click` event working.

This is `.html file`

```
<div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
 <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownMap" ngbDropdownToggle>Select Location</button>                
   <div ngbDrop4downMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownMap">

    <button class="dropdown-item" *ngFor="let country of countries" 
    (click)="mapCountry_selected(country)" >{{country}}</button>      
 </div>

</div>
```

Code in `.ts file`

```
public mapCountry_selected(country)
 {
   var c=country;
 }
```

Comment: Can you place a minimal code in somewhere like JsFiddler? Also whats ngbDrop4downMenu, should it not be ngbDropdownMenu  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to display the selected item country, you have to fake the label you are displaying.

You can have a variable `selectedCountry` which will display either the selected country or the default value "Select Location"

**The templating**

```
<div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
 <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownMap" ngbDropdownToggle>{{selectedCountry}}</button>                
   <div ngbDrop4downMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownMap">

    <button class="dropdown-item" *ngFor="let country of countries" (click)="mapCountry_selected(country)" >{{country}}</button>      
 </div>

</div>
```

**and the .ts code**

```
  countries = ["Country 1", "Country 2", "Country 3"];
  selectedCountry = 'Select Location'

  mapCountry_selected(country) {
    this.selectedCountry = country
  }
```